# Automatically Generate Google Mock Methods?

Tags: c++, methods, googletest, googlemock

I'm fairly new to C++ and Unit testing and I'm learning to use Google Mock and Google Test right now to test some code that I'm working with. Instead of writing all of the Google Mock methods manually, is there a way to point Google Mock to your class and have it automatically generate all of the Google Mock methods for all of your functions?

Someone told me they think it should be possible, but as I'm new to this (Just started learning C++ a few weeks ago) I have no idea if this is possible.

Comment: Well, it should be fairly easy to automatically deduce mock method definitions from a given interface. Though I'm not aware of such tool that does so for you (Asking for such is OT here BTW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " Instead of writing all of the Gmock methods manually, is there a way to point Gmock to your class and have it automatically generate all of the Gmock methods for all of your functions?"

Well, what I'm doing most of the time is copying a line from the interface

```
 struct IFace {
     int doThefancyOperatiion(std::string s, int i) = 0;
 };
```

and change it to

```
 struct MockIface {
       MOCK_METHOD2(doThefancyOperatiion, int (std::string s, int i));
 };
```

Looks like it can be done with `sed` or any other fairly decent tool for text replacement. Not I'm aware of a particular one, that does this for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I'm doing right now anyways. Just didn't know if this was possible or not. Didn't find anywhere where it said it was possible in the Gmock documentation.

Comment: Care to explain how to get sed to count the number of templatized C++ arguments (for `MOCK_METHOD2` vs `MOCK_METHOD3`)? Or how to use sed to know that the return type is `Foo<Bar, std::function<baz(qux)>>` and not `Foo<Bar, `?

Answer (score 6):

Quoting the gmock documentation:

> If even this is too much work for you, you'll find the gmock_gen.py
>   tool in Google Mock's scripts/generator/ directory (courtesy of the
>   cppclean project) useful. This command-line tool requires that you
>   have Python 2.4 installed. You give it a C++ file and the name of an
>   abstract class defined in it, and it will print the definition of the
>   mock class for you. Due to the complexity of the C++ language, this
>   script may not always work, but it can be quite handy when it does

https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies

So, you can just pass your header to a python script and it will output a ready to use mock implementation. From my experience, it's not always 100% correct, but fixes are relatively trivial so this solution is what I use myself.

Comment: And that's a reason to downvote my accepted answer? Really?? Asking for tools is off-topic anyways.

Comment: It was not me who did that. You are jumping to conclusions, at least, unless I am misremembering my own actions

Comment: strange. I really, really, don't remember doing that. If I did it was  by a misclick, sorry then

Comment: Seems it wasn't you if you did an upvote now. Edited to release my downvote from your answer.

Comment: `If even this is too much work for you`. What a patronizing statement. Some code generators (I'm looking at another Google product here) generates multi-megabyte C++ source code for which it is not simply laziness that motivates a code generator. Is it simply "too much work" to deliver a product instead of spending weeks transcribing out `std::unique_ptr< ::grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface < ` over and over?

Answer (score 0):

This repository [I2Mock](https://github.com/ehsan-mosadeq/I2Mock) has provided a simple script for converting a C++ interface [pure abstract calss] to both Google and Turtle mocks. You just need to give it the address of your CPP header and the generated mock class will be created next to it.